# Como buscar coincidencias de selectores CSS en consola de Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy tratando de buscar un selector especifico en el html de una pagina, para poder asi scrapear exactamente ese dato y no que me salgan otros pero no logro ver donde se pueden buscar las coincidencias

alguno sabra?

quiero buscar por ejemplo esto: `.buy-box--buy-box-item--1Qbkl`

que es una clase de un div pero quiero cuantos divs con esa misma clase tengo en la pagina para seleccionar el que es

Answer (score -1):

El selector que estas buscando se llama selector de clases

```
  <body>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="buy-box--buy-box-item--1Qbkl"></div>
      <div class="buy-box--buy-box-item--1Qbkl"></div>
      <div class="buy-box--buy-box-item--1Qbkl"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const coincidencias = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".buy-box--buy-box-item--1Qbkl"
      );
      console.log(
        " ~ file: test.html ~ line 18 ~ coincidencias",
        coincidencias
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```